# Character appear 1 by 1 animation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

My client wants the homepage where a sentence is formed character by character.
I haven't done anything like this before so I tried something on my own using `setInterval` in jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  animatorFadeIn();
});

function animatorFadeIn(){
 var outerStop = setInterval(function(){
  var data = 'This is a test animation';
  var inc = 0;
  var unit = '';
  var stop = setInterval(function()
  { 
   if(inc < data.length){
     unit = unit + data[inc];
     $('#title').html(unit);
     inc = inc + 1;
     if(inc == data.length)
       clearInterval(stop);
   }
     }, 50);
  clearInterval(outerStop);
 },1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="title"></h1>
```

This doesn't work on internet explorer version < 9

Is this the correct way of animating the text this way? Can you guys show me some other alternative ways of achieving the same result so that it will be compatible on almost all browsers?

This is the [**link**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxbpmw7x/) to the fiddle.

Comment: A side note: there's not much point in making an interval and always stopping it after the first iteration. Use `setTimeout()` instead.

Comment: That said, [the internet is full of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+typewriter+effect) for effects like this. Or are you asking how to fix this script in old IEs? In that case you'll need to be more specific than "this doesn't work."

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do it:

```
(function() {
  $.fn.onebyone = function(string, settings) {
    var stringLength = string.length,
      chars = string.split(''),
      index = 0,
      that = this;

    that.text('');

    function addLetter() {
      that.text( that.text() + chars[index] )
    }

    var write = setInterval(function() {
      addLetter();
      index++;
      if (index === stringLength) {
        clearInterval(write);
      }
    }, settings.interval);

    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
<div id="t" data-text="Hello World!"></div>

(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('#t').onebyone($('#t').data('text'), {interval: 500});
  });
})(jQuery);
```

[**See it in action.**](http://jsfiddle.net/sjao7L20/)

Another way could be to animate an original 0 width div to its full width, using white space nowrap and overflow visible :)